# Экспорт в iCal календарь

Tags: ios, calendar

Для экспорта в гугл календарь есть ссылки в формате 
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE

есть ли такое для iCal или альтернативный вариант для создания мероприятия из сайта?